# no sound indicator or sound settings after playing with hda-jack-retask

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, indicator-sound

I was playing with hda-jack-retask (changed mic input to line out output), after I finished everything was ok, system settings showed new device in sound tab, after few restarts that what happens:

In system settings at sound tab there are no output devices.
sound indicator is not statring at system startup, when I try to start it manually I get:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service

** (process:5348): WARNING **: volume-control.vala:201: pa_context_connect() failed: OK
```

and then it just stays like that, also keyboard controls are not working.
Alsamixer works fine, I'm using it to control volume right now.

From source code of volume-control.vala I see there is some problem with PulseAudio.
Could anyone help me locate resolve this problem ? Maybe pulseaudio need to be reconfigured or restarted somehow ?

Comment: Is PulseAudio running at all? See if you get errors with `pulseaudio`, or `pulseaudio -k` in CLI.

Comment: it helped! pulseaudio was not starting at all. Now I must manually run it at every startup, and then sound indicator works. Thanks!